# Finding the expectation of a characteristic function conditioned on a gaussian random variable.

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, conditional-expectation, characteristic-functions, brownian-bridge

For $X_t$ is a Brownian bridge, I have to find $E[e^{iu(X_{4/5}-\frac{1}{2} X_{3/5})}|X_{3/5}]$.

I can find the distribution of $X_{4/5}-\frac{1}{2} X_{3/5}$ with no issues, and I can see that $E[e^{iu(X_{4/5}-\frac{1}{2} X_{3/5})}]$ appears to be the characteristic function of $X_{4/5}-\frac{1}{2} X_{3/5}$. However, I'm not sure how to proceed when the function is conditional on a variable. Would appreciate some assistance.

Answer (score 0):

$E[e^{iu(X_{4/5}-\frac{1}{2} X_{3/5})}|X_{3/5}]=E[e^{iu([X_{4/5}-X_{3/5}]+\frac{1}{2} X_{3/5})}|X_{3/5}]=e^{iu/2X_{3/5}} E[e^{iu(X_{4/5}-X_{3/5})}]$. Now you can write down $E[e^{iu(X_{4/5}-X_{3/5})}]$ using the fact that $X_{4/5}-X_{3/5} \sim N(0,1/5)$

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I'm just wondering why the condition disappears after the second step?

Comment: $e^{iu/sX_{3/5}}$ is measurable w.r.t $X_{3/5}$ so it comes out of the expectation. And then  the conditioning disappears because $X_{4/5}-X_{3/5}$ is independent of $X_{3/5}$. @Risuka